# Wordpress custom blog layout

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in php coding, I want to make custom wordpress blog layout using php codes, like get title, get text, get author and give styling post summary layout. Is there any usefull tutorial that anyone can advice?

Comment: I'm not a down-voter but PLEASE use something like google and show some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WordPress Codex has some useful information that may help you. You can read more on the WordPress loop here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Standard_Loop

Some templating advice: https://codex.wordpress.org/Templates

You can also check out a very useful starter theme to see how things are done called underscores, https://github.com/Automattic/_s

Comment: Thank you for your help! Its what I need